# Primefaces menubar submenu position

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've a primefaces menubar with submenus, my application has two languages one of them is RTL.
when I switch the interface to RTL the menubar submenu still displayed to the right of it's parent.

```
          <p:menubar>
                <p:submenu label="#{msg.CreditCardsMenu}" icon="ui-icon-note" 
                    rendered="#{userAuthneticator.isAllowedMenu('CC')}">
                    <p:submenu label="#{msg.OutBoundCrossSellMenu}"
                          icon="ui-icon-circle-arrow-e"
                        rendered="#{userAuthneticator.isAllowedMenu('outCC') and request.isUserInRole('OutCC')}">
                        <p:menuitem value="#{msg.Centeral1Menu}" 
                            icon="ui-icon-minusthick"
                            action="#{followup.prepareView(4, 'Out CC','Central1')}"
                            rendered="#{userAuthneticator.user.centeral1}" ajax="false" />
                        <p:menuitem value="#{msg.Centeral2Menu}"
                            icon="ui-icon-minusthick"
                            action="#{followup.prepareView(4, 'Out CC','Central2')}"
                            rendered="#{userAuthneticator.user.centeral2}" ajax="false" />
                        <p:menuitem value="#{msg.WesternMenu}" icon="ui-icon-minusthick"
                            action="#{followup.prepareView(4, 'Out CC','Western')}"
                            rendered="#{userAuthneticator.user.western}" ajax="false" />
                        <p:menuitem value="#{msg.EasternMenu}" icon="ui-icon-minusthick"
                            action="#{followup.prepareView(4, 'Out CC','Eastern')}"
                            rendered="#{userAuthneticator.user.eastern}" ajax="false" />
                    </p:submenu>

                </p:submenu>

            </p:menubar>
```

how can I change the position of the submenu to be left instead of right.

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code here, thanks,

Comment: I added my code in the first question. Thanks